# What does "sourcing" in "Event Sourcing" stand for?

Tags: event-sourcing

What does "sourcing" stand for?

Is it that events are "sourced" from somewhere or that the state is "sourced" from events?

I can't seem to find any authoritative reference to this, aside from seemingly confusing use of "source" like "[can't source](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventSourcing.html)" and "[source the event](https://eventstore.org/docs/introduction/4.0.0/event-sourcing-basics/)".

Answer (score 0):

> What does "sourcing" stand for?

I would answer this way: it stands for the fact that the source of truth (aka: the book of record) is a journal of events.

As far as I can tell, the earliest references to the phrase "event sourcing" come from Martin Fowler, who [wrote in 2015](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventNarrative.html#EventSourcing)

> But we can go further than an audit trail, into to some very interesting territory. The enabler for this occurs when all changes to a system are caused by events - an approach that I call Event Sourcing. Another way of looking at this is that Event Sourcing happens when we can entirely derive the state of an application by processing the log of Domain Events.

Note that Fowler's 2005 understanding of [domain events](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/DomainEvent.html) doesn't *quite* align with more recent interpretations - see, for instance, [Greg Young](http://codebetter.com/gregyoung/2010/04/11/what-is-a-domain-event/) writing five years later.